# Web forms, if eval() is 0

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, eval, sqldatasource

I have a problem in a Web Forms project.
I have a gridview bound to a SqlDataSource.

In my gridview's ItemTemplate I have following code:

```
<li><asp:Literal id='eingangLiteral' runat='server' Text='<%# (int)Eval("countCallsEingang") == 0 ? "" : Eval("countCallsEingang") + " eingegangen   "%>'></asp:Literal></li>
```

The problem with this is, that my li html tag also is shown when Eval("countsCallEingang") is 0 and displayed as empty.

So I have to make the 0 check before the li tag and show the li tag only when it is not 0.
How do I form a If-Clause or something similar in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do you need the literal value? 
If not, then you could do

```
<%# (int)Eval("countCallsEingang") == 0 ? "" : "<li>" + Eval("countCallsEingang") + " eingegangen   " + "</li>" %>
```